# Wordpress filter (hook) to set value of 'autoload' to 'no' for wp_option

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, I am using a third party background processing plugin, that creates lots of entries in wp_options table. It is not programmatically setting the value of 'autoload' column to 'no'. Is there a filter (hook) that I can use to update the value of autoload for specific option name when added/updated. Please guide at your earliest.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/ executes several hooks.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, but I am not getting the one to change the value of autoload parameter. I am looking out for that.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `pre_option_{$option}` filter